# Create random String of numbers with specific requirements

Tags: java

I want to create a random String of numbers.

- From 0-9.
- 10 digits long.
- First digit cannot be a 0.
- One of the digits has to be in the String 2 times and one has to not be there at all.
- Or one digit has to be there 3 times, and 2 other digits can not be there at all.

To make this a little bit clearer here are some examples:

1223456789 - 10 digits, no starting zero, one digit (2) is there 2 times and one digit (0) is not there at all

1000345678 - 10 digits, no starting zero, one digit (0) is there 3 times and two digits (2,9) are not there at all

The starting zero is pretty easy caught with startsWith - method, but I have not found a way to check for the rest and I am not particularly good at regex while I am also not entirely sure you can even do this using regex.

For generating the random String itself, I have worked with the Random class as well as RandomStringUtils, both of which don't have restrictions on creating numbers.

Has anyone of you an idea how to achieve this?

Comment: In both of your examples, the digits that appear multiple times appear sequentially. Is this part of the specification? Or would "1030456078" still be a valid example of your "appear three times" condition?

Comment: There seems to be two parts to this problem: generating numbers, and validating the numbers. As @sprinter has pointed out, you could just solve the validation problem, then randomly generate a bunch 10 digit numbers and check them.

Comment: The sequential appearance is just by coincidence since I was pulling the numbers out of my head and just wrote em down.  In fact they can be anywhere. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is: first generate a random string with 0-9 each once and not starts with 0, then: 1. replace one of the digital will another or 2.replace two digitals with another.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(generateRandomString());
        System.out.println(generateRandomString());
    }


    public static String generateRandomString() {
        String alphabet = "0123456789";
        String result = "";
        Random random = new Random();
        // build a random string construct will 0-9 and each digital appear once
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int index = random.nextInt(alphabet.length());
            if (i == 0) { // first cannot be 0
                index = random.nextInt(alphabet.length() - 1) + 1;
            }
            String c = alphabet.substring(index, index + 1);
            result += c;
            alphabet = alphabet.replace(c, "");
        }
        return random.nextInt(2) == 0 ? shuffle1(random, result) : shuffle2(random, result);
    }

    // One of the digits has to be in the String 2 times and one has to not be there at all.
    private static String shuffle1(Random random, String result) {
        int from = random.nextInt(10);
        int to = random.nextInt(9) + 1;
        while (from == to) {
            to = random.nextInt(9) + 1;
        }
        result = result.replace(result.substring(to, to + 1), result.substring(from, from + 1));
        return result;
    }

    // One digit has to be there 3 times, and 2 other digits can not be there at all
    private static String shuffle2(Random random, String result) {
        int from = random.nextInt(10);
        int to1 = random.nextInt(9) + 1;
        int to2 = random.nextInt(9) + 1;
        while (from == to1) {
            to1 = random.nextInt(9) + 1;
        }
        while (from == to2 || to2 == to1) {
            to2 = random.nextInt(9) + 1;
        }
        result = result.replace(result.substring(to1, to1 + 1), result.substring(from, from + 1));
        result = result.replace(result.substring(to2, to2 + 1), result.substring(from, from + 1));
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Works exactly like it should be. I owe you one!

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have 10 sacks, each one of them has its corresponding number embroided on it, from 0 to 9, like this:

```
   .---.._                  
  {------'; 
   }====={    
 .´       '.   
/    .´|    \       inside there are
|      |    |  <--- stones with '1' engraved
\:    _|_   /
  -__    =.´
```

You also have a coin to flip heads or tails on your hand.

```
       .------..-                  
     ´  . /___  `.`.
   ;   / /    ´}  ; ;     ______________________________ 
  :    "|'__'  //  : :   /                              |
  '    .|/__\. } \ ' '  /_    HEAD! You shall pick 3    |
  '     /"../      ' '    |  stones from the 1st sack!  |
   ;   /  \/  ͷ   ; ;     \____________________________/
    `_/          ´ ´ 
      " -------´-´
```

First, we will decide if we will have 3 repeating numbers or 2 repeating numbers. Flip the coin to decide! Tail is 3, Head is 2. We will call this result ͷ.

Remove the sack embroided with 0 (Zero) for a moment.

Now pick ͷ (2 or 3) stones from a random sack of the 9 sacks you have in front of you. Remember, you cannot start with 0, that is why we removed it for a moment! Remove the sack you just picked from the line of sacks, forever. You cannot pick from this one anymore. Put back the 0 (Zero) sack on the line.

Place one of the stones you just picked in front of yourself. Hold ͷ-1  in your hand.

Now repeat this until you have 9 stones in your hand:

> Select a random sack, pick ONE stone from it and hold it in your hand. Remove the sack from the
>   line.

By the end of this process, you will have 9 stones in your hand, one in front of yourself. Shuffle up the ones in your hand. Place them in a straight line in front of yourself, next to the stone that was already in front of you.

You will end with 10 numbers, ͷ repetitions of the same number, won't start with zero, and the remaining sack(s) in front of you are just a side-effect of removing the sacks along the way.

Answer (score 1):

What about trying to make what you want first using the rules then construct the rest.

Here is a possible idea

Using the first rule

`One of the digits has to be in the String 2 times and one has to not be there at all.`

1. Create a LinkedList then add the numbers 1 to 9 to it.
2. Generate a random number between 0-8 (range of the indexes of the list), use the index to retrieve a value out of the list (as in delete it) then add that to the String so the first number isn't 0.
3. Add 0 back to the list so it can be used somewhere else.
4. There are now 9 numbers left in the LinkedList with the first number being non zero and already in the String variable as per step 2. From here, generate another random number in the range of the LinkedList indexes. Whatever this number is, remove it from the LinkedList add it twice to the ArrayList.
5. There are now 8 numbers left in the LinkedList, 1 non zero number in the String. and 3 numbers in the ArrayList for a total of 4 numbers in your sequence that are confirmed to be correct. You have to get another 6 numbers to complete it. So far it would look something like this.

`String sequence => "4"`

`ArrayList beingBuilt => [2, 6, 6]`

`LinkedList available => [1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 0`]

6. Seems you only can have 10 numbers, loop 6 more times through the LinkedList using a random number to pluck at a random index, delete it from LinkedList add it to ArrayList.

After this the ArrayList should have 9 numbers, you could shuffle it to make it more random then convert it to a String and append to on the end of the sequence. Your rule should be satisfied now.

To make it more random you could manipulate how you pluck out numbers from the LinkedList and also the last rule you had you could change it for that too fairly simply. I used a LinkedList due to faster deletes, I did think about using a set but perhaps more work to handle the random number index being mapped to a number that actually exists in the set.

Just an idea though

Comment: I think it is cool that you and I reached the same same algorithm and explained it in a very different way :B

Answer (score 0):

If you're not too concerned about performance then the simplest thing would be to just generate random lists of numbers and check them against your conditions until you get one that works. Best to do the filtering as numbers and then convert to a string at the end rather than using regular expressions.

```
public String getRandomInts() {
    Random random = new Random();
    int[] ints;
    do {
        ints = random.ints(10, 0, 10).toArray();
    } while (!meetsCriteria(ints));
    return Arrays.stream(ints).mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(""));
}

private boolean meetsCriteria(int[] ints) {
    if (ints[0] == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    if (frequency(ints, 0) == 1 
            && frequency(ints, 1) == 8
            && frequency(ints, 2) == 1) {
        return true;
    }
    if (frequency(ints, 0) == 2 
            && frequency(ints, 1) == 7
            && frequency(ints, 3) == 1) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private int frequency(int[] ints, int count) {
    return (int) IntStream.range(0, 10)
            .filter(n1 -> Arrays.stream(ints).filter(n2 -> n1 == n2).count() == count)
            .count();
}
```

Comment: This is like "bogosorting" the problem. Noooo!

Comment: @caulitomaz Some of my best friends are bogosorters :-) Seriously if OP wants truly random digits with just some filtered out then this might be the most reasonable way to go about it. You could generate digits that satisfy the criteria but you are going to end up skewing the distribution unless you do a lot of maths up front. I doubt performance will really be a consideration (unlike sorting algorithms).

Comment: I'm worried about the time complexity of this. Hitting the criteria might be as hard as winning the lottery. How many numbers inside the 10ˆ10 probability hit the criteria?

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. I tried the code and it gave me this Array [3, 9, 2, 3, 6, 1, 2, 5, 3, 1]
So its not meeting the criteria.

Comment: @user5760519 Just to be clear, the criteria in my code are inequalities (i.e the criteria are that at least one digit satisifies the count). Are you intending that it be exactly one or two? If that's the case do the rest have to occur a single time? If that's the case they'll need to be equalities instead.

Comment: @sprinter Check out the example numbers I posted. Thats how they should be. Either 2 same digits or 3 with the missing one or two numbers respectively

Comment: You answer is much straight forward then my version, but as comments before, the time complexity is way too much.

Comment: @user5760519 Ok understand the question better now - all the other digits in the string need to occur once. I've changed the code and generated 1000 strings in a test programme.

Comment: @xfx Generated 1000 in under a second on my laptop. Not sure how quick OP wants.

Comment: Do the math: The total count match requirement is about(as near as permutation of 0-9) 10!, the total count of 10 digitals number(0-leading include) is pow(10, 10).

Comment: @sprinter I just tried your code aswell and it works fine. Can I select both suggestions as solutions? I dont think I can but they both work and do what they should.